# Get the data from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

| Word | Clue |
| --- | --- |
| PAT | Action done while saying "Good dog" |
| RASCALS | Mischief-makers |
| PEN | It might click for a writer |

I want to take the data from Clue column by Index.

I have used the **iloc** but I want the data in string format to use it somewhere else, the format it gives it back is not what I want.

```
x = df.iloc[[0],[1]]
```

It will show it as a dataframe, and when I use it in the following code it also shows the Clue(Column Name):

```
y = "The answer for: {} Crossword Clue.".format(x)
```

Output:

The answer for: Clue\n0 Action done while saying "Good dog" Crossword Clue.

but I want:

```
The answer for: Action done while saying "Good dog" Crossword Clue.
```

Comment: Use `df.iloc[0].Clue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the square brackets when using `.iloc`. When you pass lists as indexes for rows and columns in `.iloc`, it assumes you are trying to pull multiple rows and columns and returns a `DataFrame` instead of the value from a single cell as a string, as you are expecting.

```
x = df.iloc[0,1]    #<----
y = "The answer for: {} Crossword Clue.".format(x)

print(y)
```

```
'The answer for: Action done while saying "Good dog" Crossword Clue.'
```

---

You can see how pandas reacts to different objects as inputs to the `.iloc` below

```
df.iloc[0,1]   #OUTPUT IS STRING

# 'Action done while saying "Good dog"'

#--------------------------------------

df.iloc[0,[1]]   #OUTPUT IS SERIES

#Clue    Action done while saying "Good dog"
#Name: 0, dtype: object

#--------------------------------------


df.iloc[[0],1]   #OUTPUT IS SERIES

#0    Action done while saying "Good dog"
#Name: Clue, dtype: object

#--------------------------------------

df.iloc[[0],[1]]   #OUTPUT IS DATAFRAME

#                                  Clue
#0  Action done while saying "Good dog"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is

```
x = data.iloc[0][1]
y = "The answer for: {str} Crossword Clue".format(str = x)
```

which returns what you wanted